# Pseudo-element Hover

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the background of my pseudo element but I'm having a hard time at it I don't know if I should use and ID instead of a class but that shouldn't be the error from my PoV, I have 4 items in my menu and I want all of them to switch the pseudo-element background to white so here's my code.

```css
.menu li a:hover::after{
    background: #FFF;
}
.menu a::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: .25rem;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -.25rem;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.menu li:nth-child(1) a::after{
    background: #da4167;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a white background to all links just add the background-color to .menu a::after. If I understood you correctly.

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}
.menu li {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #da4167;
}
.menu li a:hover::after {
  background: #fff;
}
.menu li a{
  color: #da4167;
  display: block;
}
.menu a::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: .25rem;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -.25rem;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #da4167;    
}

.simple li {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;;
}
.simple li a {
  color: #da4167;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  border-bottom: 0.25rem #da4167 solid;
}
.simple li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #da4167;
  border-bottom: 0.25rem #fff solid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="simple">
  <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What I was trying to do is the following, in my menu bar I have 4 elements and I wanted a stripe (::after pseudo-element) below the text of each element, the stripe will have a color (i.e. red), and once I hover over the element I wanted the stripe to go white and the rest of the element(button) go red. I managed to make it work once I add 
.menu li:nth-child(1) a:hover::after
{
    background: #FFF;
}
but since I want all of my elements have this change I thought that it would work without the nth-child, however it didn't work that way :S

I hope that I explained myself as I wanted

Comment: @JoséLuisCastañedaLeón I've updated snippet and also added a simpler variant with border and without pseudo-element.

Comment: That really worked as I expected, thanks!

Comment: Great. Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Just make this change:

```
.menu li a:hover:after{
    background: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: an explanation of why this works(and his doesn't) would help the OP learn.